# Line within same x value linking subjects in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, tidyverse

I am fairly new to R so I apologise if my code is a bit messy.
I am looking to link up the same subjects for each x value, when each x value has different conditions.

My current code is below, I have tried adding geom_line and grouping by subject but this appears to take the average of the subjects in each x value and link between x values.

Code below

```
Dwplot <-
  ggplot(data = DwDataCat, aes(x = cloud, y = weight)) +
  geom_point(
    mapping = aes(color = condition,
                  group = condition),
    position = position_jitterdodge(
      jitter.width = 0.2,
      jitter.height = 0,
      dodge.width = 0.9
    )
  ) +
  facet_wrap(reorder(DwDataCat$category, desc(DwDataCat$category)), scales = "free") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0.2, 0.25)))

print(Dwplot)
```

[What my code currently does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cd5Ip.png)
[Example of what I would like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TvfKO.png)

I have tried using geom_line however this appeared to take the average of each subject and link between each value rather than within

Comment: Hi, Could you give a part of your data as example to test?

Comment: Hi CG1992, Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would be helpful you would please share a reproducible example including a small sample of your data set. You will likely get more helpful answers. You can do this best by using You can do this best by using `dput(head(my.example.data))`. Edit your question and include the output of the `structure(...)`. You may have to create a new custom data set and then use `geom_line` or `geom_segment` to connect the points. You have a special case of this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-connect-paired-points-with-lines-in-scatterplot-in-ggplot2-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else has an issue in the future I managed to solve my issue.

I ended up changing the x value so that the two conditions (coloured dots) were represented as different x values, to create the illusion that there was only 1 x value per condition I created a new variable which coded the conditions to integer values in order to create x breaks halfway between the integers.
Here is image of updated plot: [updated plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFrJY.png)

```
    DwDataCat <- DwData %>% 
  #this elseif creates a new column, for those that have either T1 or T2 in the cloud column
  #the data in the new column 'category' will be target, otherwise it will be decoy
  mutate(category = ifelse(cloud %in% c("T1", "T2"), "target","decoy"),
         #combines the values in cloud and condition, this was needed to create
         #the 4 new x values required
         combined = paste(cloud, condition),
         #in order to create breaks (aka ticks) between the x values, I have to assign
         #an integer to each 'combined' variable called 'uniquenumeric'
         uniquenumeric = case_when(
           combined == "T1 baseline" ~ 1L, #the L makes it an integer value
           combined == "T1 decoy" ~ 2L,
           combined == "T2 baseline" ~ 3L,
           combined == "T2 decoy" ~ 4L,
           combined == "D1 baseline" ~ 5L,
           combined == "D1 decoy" ~ 6L,
           combined == "D2 baseline" ~ 7L,
           combined == "D2 decoy" ~ 8L
         )) %>% 
  #need to find means and sd to make the errorbar
  #as error bar needed for each x value, group by the x value uniquenumeric
  group_by(uniquenumeric) %>% 
  #calulating the mean and sd for each x value
  mutate(meanc = mean(weight), sdc = sd(weight)) %>% 
  ungroup()

Dwplot <-  
  ggplot(data = DwDataCat, aes(x = uniquenumeric, y = weight)) +
  geom_point(
    mapping = aes(
      color = condition
    ),
    position = position_jitterdodge(jitter.width = 0.2, jitter.height = 0, dodge.width = 0.9)  #stops the points from being ontop of one another 
    
  )+
  facet_wrap(reorder(DwDataCat$category, desc(DwDataCat$category)), scales = "free") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(add = c(0.2, 0.25))) +
  #added colour to make the lines grey 
  geom_line(mapping = aes(group = (interaction(subject,cloud))), color = "grey") +
  #As the x scale is now an integer, breaks were created as midpoints between the x scale values
  #to give the illusion of 2 values per facet instead of 4 with the correct lavels
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1.5, 3.5, 5.5, 7.5), labels = c("target 1", "target 2", "distractor 1", "distractor 2")) +
  #create the error bar, as it is for 95% CI limits, 1.96 is used
    #uses standard CI formula
    #ymin creates bottom of bar, ymax top, width adjusted 
    geom_errorbar(mapping = aes(ymin = meanc - 1.96 * (sdc / sqrt(23)), ymax = meanc + 1.96 * (sdc / sqrt(23))),
                width = 0.2) + 
  theme(
    #remove facetwrap labels
    strip.text = element_blank(), 
    # Set panel background to transparent
        panel.background = element_blank(), 
    # Remove major grid lines
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(),  
    # Remove minor grid lines
        panel.grid.minor = element_blank()
    )+ 
  
    #add titles
  labs(title = "Normalised Decision Weights in Consistent Non-Target and Decoy Conditions",
       x = NULL,
       y = "decision weight") +
    #change colour of points
  scale_color_manual(values = c("baseline" = "orange", "decoy" = "blue"),
                     labels = c("Baseline", "Decoy"), 
                     #ensure no label for the key
                     name = NULL)


print(Dwplot)
```